# Query data not represented by model classes using Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I stumbled accross [this site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) about limitations of the Entity Framework (Core) stating one can only select data represented by model classes.

Now I want to implement something basic like statistics holding sums and counts of mulitple fields in multiple tables. Currently I am using multiple selects (one for each field in each table) which is not optimal because the statistics are placed on each page and therefor queried often.

I created the following SQL statement which queries the result with one call but I can't figure out to execute it from the MVC controller and return it.

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN temp.val1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) res1,
SUM(CASE WHEN temp.val1 = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) res2,
SUM(temp.valT) res3
FROM (
    SELECT x.Field1 AS val1, x.Field2 AS valT FROM Table1 x
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 0 AS val1, y.Field2 AS valT FROM Table2 y
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 0 AS val1, z.Field2 AS valT FROM Table3 z
) temp
```

Comment: Well, since as you noticed EF Core does not currently support it, you should resort to old good ADO.NET, e.g. get db connection, create command, execute reader, consume the result (populate a class) etc.

Comment: I decided to query this data with good old ADO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use may use libraries like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) to execute this query and map it to non-model class: